# How do I show "daily hits" in any URL (visits/page loads)?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need to count page views (from any url on my site including search pages) and show them on my site but I can't manage to make it work. I wanted to show the numer of times a page is loaded daily but at this point I don't really care whether I get pageviews, single visitors, or any kind of visits, as long as I do have some kind of counter.

Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. The easiest way is to use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Comment: +1. The easiest way is always to get someone else to do the work for you.

Comment: Sorry I meant I wanted to display them on my site. I just corrected the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Thyamine's answer would be conceptually correct, then. You'd need to code some PHP to count every time a page is rendered. You could use a global variable (poor solution), or store in a database.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one of the free web statistics programs out there to just analyze your web logs.  They'll be more fully featured than just counting visits, and there will be no overhead of database transactions just because someone is visiting a page.

http://awstats.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Sorry I meant I wanted to display them on my site. I just corrected the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Well in that case if you could simply add a function at the top of each page that saves the visit.  Have it save the page visited, the IP address, and a datestamp.  Then later you can just count the number of visits per page, or attempt to do some sort of group/sorting based on IP or time period.

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd have to say it: displaying number of views is **SO** 2000.

Well, now to the actual question, you'll have to identify each page and find out how flexible that can be:

```
/?p=1
/?p=1&q=2
/?p=1&s=1
```

Those might be the paths and might be referring to the same object, so you'll have to grab it and parse it if necessary. Now, just save it to a table in your database and increase the counter each time a new view is there.

Comment: it's not to create a 2000s page, it really isn't I swear. lol

Answer (score 0):

Back on Visonary Software Solutions' track. I would use a Google Analytics-based solution too, perhaps you will use it on your site anyway. I did a quick search and found a tutorial on how to create counters like you wanted, displaying Analytics data. It doesn't look so complicated.

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/feedcount-like-google-analytics-counter/

As far as I can tell, there are quite a lot of extensions for this purpose for the popular CMSs:
For Drupal: http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics_counter
For WordPress: http://analytics.blogspot.com/2009/05/share-your-google-analytics-data-with.html